# Pandas To Add an Index to Sum the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has transposed as below. Years heading are the index and {A,B,C,D, E} are the columns.

I like to know how can I add a SUM to add all the values in rows A, B, C, D, & E. Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: You just want to sum all columns? `df.sum(axis=1)`

Comment: Additionally, you can also get the total for each year using `df.loc[len(df)] = df.sum(axis= 0)`.  With `axis=0`, it will go top to bottom, with `axis=1`, it will go left to right

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,4], 'b': [10,20,45], 'c': [1,2,5]})
df
df["sum"] = df.sum(axis=1)
df
```